# Accessing input and output tensors of a tensorflow 2.0 SavedModel via the C API

Tags: c, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow2.0, c-api

I am having trouble running inference from a tensorflow 2.0 SavedModel loaded the C_API, because I cannot access the input and output operations by name.

I load the session via TF_LoadSessionFromSavedModel(...) successfully:

```
#include <tensorflow/c/c_api>

...

TF_Status* status = TF_NewStatus();
TF_Graph*  graph  = TF_NewGraph();
TF_Buffer* r_opts = TF_NewBufferFromString("",0);
TF_Buffer* meta_g = TF_NewBuffer();

TF_SessionOptions* opts = TF_NewSessionOptions();
const char* tags[] = {"serve"};

TF_Session* session = TF_LoadSessionFromSavedModel(opts, r_opts, "saved_model/tf2_model", tags, 1, graph, meta_g, status);

if ( TF_GetCode(status) != TF_OK ) exit(-1); //does not happen
```

However, I get an error when trying to setup the input and output tensors using:

```
TF_Operation* inputOp  = TF_GraphOperationByName(graph, "input"); //works with "serving_default_input"
TF_Operation* outputOp = TF_GraphOperationByName(graph, "prediction"); //does not work
```

The names I am passing as arguments are assigned to the input and output keras layers of the saved model, but are not in the loaded `graph`. Running `saved_model_cli` (following the tf SavedModel tutorial [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#load_a_savedmodel_in_c)) shows that the tenors with these names exist under the `SignatureDef` `serving_default`, so I guess that I need to instantiate `serving_default` into a graph (in other words create a graph according to the signature), however I could not find a way to do this using the C API.

Note that tensorflows's C_API [test](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/c/c_api_test.cc) uses C++ tensorflow/core/ functionality to load a signature definition map from the metagraph and uses it to find input and output operation names, but I would like to avoid the dependency on C++.

Also note that accessing the operations by name works for frozen .pb graphs, however this format is being deprecated.

Thanks in advance for any ideas and hints!

Comment: This tutorial seems to have a solution to this, albeit not so elegant because you still need to analyse the defined signatures via saved_model_cli https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/deploying-tensorflow-2-1-as-c-c-executable-1d090845055c

Answer (score 6):

Currently (as of May 2020) the Tensorflow C API doesn't officially support the SavedModel (**tensorflow 2.0**) format, even though they will probably release the functionality [soon](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/c/experimental/).

Regardless, you can use the **default** SignatureDefs defined when exporting the model and find the names of the input and output tensors using the [saved_model_cli](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#show_command) tool.

Say you saved your model using

```py
model.save('/path/to/model/folder')
```

You then open a bash and do

```sh
cd /python/folder/bin/
saved_model_cli show --dir /path/to/model/folder --tag_set serve --signature_def serving_default
```

*(the actual location of `saved_model_cli` varies, but it is installed by default when using anaconda on the bin/ folder)*

it will yield by default something like:

```sh
serving_default
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
  inputs['graph_input'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_DOUBLE
      shape: (-1, 28, 28)
      name: serving_default_graph_input:0
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
  outputs['graph_output'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (-1, 10)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:0
Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

In this case, **serving_default_graph_input** is the input tensor name, and **StatefulPartitionedCall** is the output tensor name. You can then load those using the `TF_GraphOperationByName()`.

With C API support for Tensorflow 2 you'd be able to [save the model with a set of defined SignatureDefs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#saving_a_custom_model) and then load the desired `concrete_function()`, without having to worry about tensor names. This current method, however should still work.

Comment: There is also an option `--all` which you can use for `saved_model_cli` to show all information, e.g, all Signature Def keys.